# Xcode, cocoapods + nib file, s.resources = ['*.{xib}'] not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I have one trouble.
I created simple project and in result have next files: ViewController.h, ViewController.m, ViewController.xib, ViewController.podspec and LICENSE.

```
Structure of ViewController.podspec:
Pod:: Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = "ViewController"
  s.version          = "0.1.0"
  s.summary          = "Some text"
  s.homepage         = "setmypage"
  s.license          = 'MIT'
  s.author           = { "Oleksii" => "oleksii@site.com" }
  s.source           = { :path => "." }
  s.platform     = :ios
  s.requires_arc = true
  s.source_files = '*.{h,m,xib}'
  s.resources = ['*.{xib}']

end
```

I created simple new project and added folder with Pod.

after I did pod lib lint for my Pod 
and do pod install this pod.

```
Structure Podfile:
platform :ios
pod "ViewController", :path => "testPod/"
    pod 'ViewController'
```

Ok. I had project with my Pod. But when I'd tried to Build my project I received 
**Unable to run command 'StripNIB ViewController.nib' - this target might include its own product.**

What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem. You should not include the xib in the source_files parameter in your podspecs:

```
 s.source_files = '*.{h,m,xib}'
 s.resources = ['*.{xib}']
```

My podspecs was a little bit different than yours because by default cocoapod version 0.39 was setting a wildcard in the source_files which was obviously too inclusive, even if my xib were included as resources (resource_bundle):

```
 s.source_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*.{h,m}'
 s.resource_bundles = {
     'MyPodBundle' => ['Pod/Classes/**/*.xib']
 }
```

So make sure you do not include your xib as source_files

Answer (score 1):

The possible cause for this your listing your product's target under target dependencies. In xcode select your target and under `Build Phases` look at the `Dependencies list` your products target should not be listed there.

Also check your `Bundle Resources` and `Link Binary with Libraries` you can't have your product listed there.

Comment: 1) Target Dependencies (0 Items); Link Binary with Libraries contain "LibPods.a" with red color name

Comment: In Copy Bundle Resources (4 Items): Main.storyboard, ViewController.podspec, LaunchScreen.xib, Images.xcassets